# How can I create a github actions workflow that deploys a nifi container using terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform, github-actions

I'm trying to use github actions to create a workflow that deploys a nifi container using terraform. I tried deloying nifi with just terraform and it works and here is the main.tf file :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "nifi_image" {
  name         = "apache/nifi:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nifi" {
  image = docker_image.nifi_image.image_id
  name  = "nifi"
  ports {
    internal = 8443
    external = 8443
  }
  env = ["SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=****",
    "SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=******"]
}
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
  name = "nifi_net"
}
```

so now I tried automating this with actions with this yaml file :

```
name: Deploy NiFi Container with Terraform

on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy_nifi:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.0.0

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply
```

The terraform apply step has been running for 2 hours and I don't what went wrong, it doesn't throw ny error it just seems like it's gonna run forever. Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: I think for that you need to use a Docker-in-Docker image, if such an image exists for GitHub actions.

Comment: I actually just added the flag -auto-approve to the terraform apply command and it worked but the problem now is how do I access the app. Cause now the container is running inside the runner right ? so how do I access it ?

Comment: Why do you want to run container on host agent? Is this GitHub hosted agent? If yes, than it would be recovered to default setting once your workflow finished.